# Can SPARQL OPTIONAL be used with INSERT DATA?

Tags: rdf, sparql, triplestore, fuseki

I want to insert several triples to my JENA FUSEKI store at once. These triples will be based on user input, but  I would like to give the users the option to leave certain input fields blank without breaking the query.

How would I go about this, given that I would really like to be able to insert all the values that exist at once.

I have searched for how to use INSERT DATA with OPTIONAL but I can't find anywhere that explains how to do? Perhaps its not possible and i am approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `INSERT {....} WHERE { ... }` then any triples in the insert template which are invalid data, such as having an unbound variable, are simply dropped but the rest of the triples from template+current result from `WHERE` are inserted.

Comment: does that the OPTIONAL clause is never required in any INSERT or DELETE statement?